# SSRS 2016 - subscription subject from variable

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, subscriptions

1. I need to pass a current date variable dynamically to SSRS subscription subject. Is it possible when using standard subscription ? 
   I know it may be obtained using data-driven subscription but then I get report sent as many times as number of rows in the report, and I only need the report to be sent once.

   I just need to have something like "Report XXX, @GETDATE()" in subject.
2. Is it possible to also set dynamic report name in Excel file sent using the SSRS subscription ?

Comment: why not return just one row (like select top 1) in your data driven subscription dataset but let the report return everything?? That way you get the benefits of the data driven subscription as well as making things easier for yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the Execution Time of the report using `@ExecutionTime`, see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/e-mail-delivery-in-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017). However, you want to make sure the execution time represents when the report was rendered or when the subscription processed the report, I am sure it is the former and it could be problematic for snapshot/cached reports. For non-cached reports this should be the current date outside of the edge case of crossing midnight server time.